# Python - "ImportError: No module named"

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, bitcoin

I keep getting an `ImportError: No module named bitcoin` message when I run my code.

I am in my Atom interpreter and typed the following code below based on some YouTube videos. However, I get an I am in my Atom interpreter and typed the following code below based on some YouTube videos. However, I get an `ImportError` message. My Python3 seems like it is not able to find the location of the module in my computer. I'm assuming I need to do something with `sys.path`.

Please note, I am not a coder, and I am unfamiliar with the coding jargon.

**Code:**

```
from bitcoin import *
priv = random_key()
print(priv)
```

**Otuput:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/User/Atom - private key", line 1, in <module>
    from bitcoin import *
ImportError: No module named bitcoin
```

Comment: Update the code as per the formatting rule present [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)

Comment: have you installed bitcoin ?

Answer (score 1):

After a few days of labor intensive searches, I finally found the solution! I had to type this in the terminal.

python -m pip install bitcoin

I believe I previously did the following:

pip install bitcoin

I don't know what this is the case so some explanation for my own understanding would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you haven't installed [bitcoin](https://pypi.org/project/bitcoin/) module in your machine.

Open the terminal and copy this and hit enter.

`pip install bitcoin`

and try to import bitcoin module. Hope this helps.

Comment: I already did "pip install bitcoin" in the Terminal. I believe it has something to do with my PATH. My PATH is in the following director: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/ .... However, the module is located here: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bitcoin/. ... It seems like I need to set something up to look for the module in that second path.

Comment: Try adding the `site-packages` to your path.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the directory **site-packages** inside **path** variable in your Windows SO.